# How do you search for an option with a value that may have a &#34; or ' in the string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id='test' size='1'><option value='this&#34;'>this&#34;</option></select>
```

Neither of these work:

```
if ($('#test option[value="this&#34;"]').length == 0 ) {
   $('body').append('true');
}
else {$('body').append('false');}
if ($("#test option[value='this&#34;']").length == 0 ) {
   $('body').append('true');
}
else {$('body').append('false');}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A7SJj/1/)

**EDIT:**

The question may be over simplified.  The value string is actually a variable that is derived from another source, so I won't know where to add an escape character.

I would have thought this: `var temp = mySTRING.replace('\"','\\\"');` would have worked, but it didn't...

Comment: have you tried var temp = mySTRING.replace("&#34;", "\"");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the escape character, to match the quotation mark.

```
if ($("#test option[value='this\"']").length == 0 ) {
    $('body').append('true');
}
else {$('body').append('false');}
```

**UPDATE**

In response to your update, you said that the value string is inside a variable, thus you can replace it with the escape character.

```
var value = "this&#34;";
value = value.replace("&#34;", "\"");

if ($("#test option[value='" + value  + "']").length == 0 ) {
    $('body').append('true');
}
else {$('body').append('false');}
```

Check the [working JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/A7SJj/6/)

Comment: This looks rather weird. The string `'#test option[value="this\""]'` is enclosed with apostrophes, meaning the escape in `\"` is invalid (ignored). Thus the selector engine receives `'#test option[value="this""]'` which doesn't look really valid.

Comment: I've switched the `'` with `"` and it still works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/A7SJj/6/ Could you have a look? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, with single quotes around the attribute value as `"#test option[value='this\"']"` looks fine. However, `'#test option[value="this\""]'` as in the answer looks a bit fishy. Though it seems to somehow work too. I guess the tokenizer looks for a closing `"]` so that a `"` in the middle of the attribute value doesn't break it, though it is still rather weird. `=]`

Comment: Yeah i was wondering as well how the tokenizer got it right. Learned something new today. Have updated answer, cheers `=]`

Comment: BTW in your replace `"\""` === `'"'`, just nitpicking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter function with a regex to get all options with a value that contains `'` or `"`

```
var x = $('#test option').filter(function () {
    return /'|"/.test(this.value);
});
if (x.length) {
    $('body').append(x.length + ' true');  
} else {
    $('body').append('false');
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dxDWe/)

Comment: No need to escape the quotes inside a regex.

Comment: This looks correct, the `&#34;` is decoded to `'` by the HTML parser before being parsed as the DOM element value. +1